# Is "склизкий" still alive and doing well?

Tags: прилагательные, диалект, metathesis

When I was a child in a Russian school, *склизкий* was sort of *the* textbook example of a dialectal variation. We always found it very peculiar.

Dal gives this:

> СКОЛЬЗИТЬ, скользнуть, скалзывать; или **склизнуть, склизнуть**; пск. слизгать, **новг. склёзить**, подвигаться по гладкому, как санный полоз, волоком или трением. Колесо катится, а полоз скользит. Верхний пласт земли скользит по наклонному глиняному пласту. И гусь скользит по гладкому льду. Старик скользнул на лощеном полу, и расшибся, поскользнулся и упал. В гололедицу и лошадь скользит. Скользиться, или скользать, сколзать, —ся, или **новг. склезать и —ся**, скользить с разбегу по льду, как ребятишки тешатся. Пойдем на лед, сколзать! Сколзанка, новг. склёзанка, чистое место на льду, где ребятишки сколзаются. Скользель, и пск. сковзель, сколзанка, гнездалка, ледяная горушка. Скользкий (хлеско, нареч.) **вост. склезкий, сев. новг. склизкий, слизкий, южн. слезкий** зап. глёздкий и хлёский, гладкий, не дающий упору ногам и рукам, на чем скользишь, что скользит из рук; гладкий, и притом мокрый, жирный, или покрытый слизью;

Etc., emphasis mine.

Now, this quote is from like 150 years ago. And it's been a while since my school time, too. Fast forward twenty years or so, I've never actually encountered *склизкий* in the wild. Not once.

Is this variation still used in the Novdorod dialect? Or other dialects, even? Can you cite any recent sightings of it in the wild? Or has it just died out for good, never to return? (If so, when?)

Comment: I can say confidently that this word is used at least in the Rostov region

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the склизкий is still doing fine. It is not used very often, however mostly you can hear it when talking about a fish or a frog (last two lines of your example). Here whats [search in National Corpus](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%EA%EB%E8%E7%EA%E8%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) gives:

> Пал Палыч начал чувствовать в груди противную дрожь, как будто холодная **склизкая** толстая жаба забралась прямо в душу. [Олег Павлов. Карагандинские девятины, или Повесть последних дней // «Октябрь», 2001]
>
> тёплых, солёных вод, в которых плавали **склизкие** медузы... [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000]
>
> И нащупывалось что-то ещё, **склизкое**, хитрое, уходящее из пальцев, но что это ― он уловить пока не мог, только чувствовал. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)]
>
> Прекрасная золотая рыбка на ощупь оказалась какой-то **склизкой** гадостью. [Михаил Шишкин. Письмовник (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, склизкий, is still alive and native used. If anything have this property - it mean that if you hand touch it you'll have thin layer of softy and hydrate dirt.

Answer (score 2):

склизкий has some yucky undertone.  When we mention a slug we can say "склизкий слизень" for example. But in the article it mean slippery (because of North Novgorod dialect) and the word is not used as "slippery" in ordinary, colloquial conversations

Answer (score 0):

I just used it in "склизкая мякоть хлеба" meaning something in between "скользкий" and "слизь"-)) And was very surprised to find that word to exist) May be it was spoken in Smolensk, were i spent my childhood 30 years ago. However it's posible, that this word is reinvented every time, cause it's juicy))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'склизкий' is definitely used in the meaning of covered with a thin layer of slim and, thus, giving an unpleasant feeling when being touched. Although, talking about a slippery road, for example, it is never used. Instead it is better to use the word 'скользкий'.